# How do I add a UIView to a scrollview that doesn't move?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview that scrolls vertically through a large UIView. I want to add another smaller UIView on top of it that stays in the same spot (floating) regardless of where you scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add the smaller UIView to the ScrollView's superview?

Assuming your view hierarchy is as follows:

- UIView (main)

  - ScrollView

    - UIView (large)

Add your small UIView as follows and fix its position

- UIView (main)

  - ScrollView

    - UIView (large)
  - UIView (small)

Comment: In addition to this, set that view's `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO, so it doesn't interfere with the scroll gestures on the scroll view.

Comment: How do I start a new line on this reply. Every time I press enter it "Save Edits."

Comment: I'm finding it impossible to reply using this comment formatting. How can I reply with bullet points like the original reply.

Comment: Also I tried the view hierarchy on the reply but I can't see the UIView (small) on the simulator. I can see it just fine in IB though.

Comment: Make sure that the UIView (small) is in front of the ScrollView. On your main view, call `self.bringSubviewToFront(smallView)` See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront: for reference